# R counting instances of a specific value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data.frame as below

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Item.Nbr supply demand
1   82078-002          1  1
2   82078-007           2 0
3   82078-007          4 0
4   82078-007           0 0
5   82078-007           0 7")
> df
   Item.Nbr supply demand
1 82078-002      1      1
2 82078-007      2      0
3 82078-007      4      0
4 82078-007      0      0
5 82078-007      0      7
```

I want to count how many times 0 supply and demand occurs by Item.Nbr, I also want to know how many times both the supply and the demand are 0 by Item.Nbr

```
   Item.Nbr 0_supply 0_demand 0_both
1 82078-002      0      0       0
2 82078-007      2      3       1
```

Comment: my bad. "part number"= Item.Nbr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using base R `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(. ~ Item.Nbr, data=transform(df, both=supply+demand), FUN=function(x) sum(x==0) )
#or
aggregate(
  cbind(supply,demand,both=supply+demand) ~ Item.Nbr, data=df, FUN=function(x) sum(x==0) 
)

#   Item.Nbr supply demand both
#1 82078-002      0      0    0
#2 82078-007      2      3    1
```

Or in `dplyr` if that's your bag (with a nod to @akrun):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(both= supply+demand) %>%
  group_by(Item.Nbr) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(!.)))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#
#   Item.Nbr supply demand both
#1 82078-002      0      0    0
#2 82078-007      2      3    1
```

Comment: Or `dplyr`  `df %>% mutate(both= supply+demand) %>% group_by(Item.Nbr) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(!.)))`

Comment: Hell throw a data table one up too `setDT(df)[, c(.SD, .(both = supply + demand))][, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x == 0)), by = Item.Nbr]` *Hopes for nod

Comment: what would l do if my dataframe df has many more columns. But i am interested only in supply, demand and Item.Nbr and their summary as asked above. Should i create a subset dataframe from df and then run above command?

Comment: @user2543622 - you can do: `aggregate(cbind(supply,demand,both=supply+demand) ~ Item.Nbr, data=df, FUN=function(x) sum(x==0) )`